# Loading image from url fails

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to load some icons from url using Coil. But it never shows on screen.

code:

```
   Image(
        painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(icon),
        contentDescription = "condition icon"
    )
```

When I log the icon variable I got the url without problems:

> icon: //cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/night/113.png

But the image doesn't appear on the screen, any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by adding https: before the url. It seems like Coil can't add this by default like it happens in the browser.

Comment: Mark your comment as the solution

Answer (score 1):

```kotlin
CoilImage(
  imageModel = imageUrl,
  // Crop, Fit, Inside, FillHeight, FillWidth, None
  contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
  // shows a placeholder while loading the image.
  placeHolder = ImageBitmap.imageResource(R.drawable.placeholder),
  // shows an error ImageBitmap when the request failed.
  error = ImageBitmap.imageResource(R.drawable.error)
)
```

This should work as a charm ([link](https://github.com/skydoves/landscapist#coil))